# Wifi stopped working after kernel update (Ubuntu 14.04 on MacBook Air 2014)

Tags: 14.04, drivers, wireless, macbook-air

I have to run Ubuntu 14.04 on a MacBook Air 2014. After installing the OS years ago, I remember having to install a wifi driver manually using an ethernet connection. Wifi has worked flawlessly ever since, until today.

After being prompted by System Updater to do a routine kernel update and restart afterwards, my wifi suddenly stopped working.

When I type "wifi on" on the command line, I now get:

```
wifi      = none (no device)
```

And the command "sudo modprobe wl" now gives me:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found.
```

After reading other threads, I tried reinstalling the bcmwl-kernel-source package, to no avail.

For reference, the relevant portion of the output of sudo lspci -v is:

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. Device 0117
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Memory at b0600000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Memory at b0400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2M]
    Capabilities: [48] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [68] Vendor Specific Information: Len=44 <?>
    Capabilities: [ac] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [13c] Device Serial Number 8c-29-00-ff-ff-00-00-01
    Capabilities: [150] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [160] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [1b0] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [220] #15
```

Thank you for your help

Edit:

"sudo dpkg -s bcmwl-kernel-source" gives:

```
Package: bcmwl-kernel-source
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: admin
Installed-Size: 7902
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Source: bcmwl
Version: 6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~0.1
Replaces: bcmwl-modaliases
Depends: dkms, linux-libc-dev, libc6-dev
Conflicts: bcmwl-modaliases
Description: Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source
 This package contains Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver
 for use with Broadcom's BCM4311-, BCM4312-, BCM4313-, BCM4321-,
 BCM4322-, BCM43224-, and BCM43225-, BCM43227- and BCM43228-based
 hardware.
Modaliases: wl(pci:v000014E4d00004311sv*sd*bc02sc80i*, pci:v000014E4d00004312sv*sd*bc02sc80i*, pci:v000014E4d00004313sv*sd*bc02sc80i*, pci:v000014E4d00004315sv*sd*bc02sc80i*, pci:v000014E4d00004727sv*sd*bc02sc80i*, pci:v000014E4d00004328sv*sd*bc02sc80i*, pci:v000014E4d00004328sv*sd*bc02sc80i*, pci:v000014E4d00004329sv*sd*bc02sc80i*, pci:v000014E4d0000432asv*sd*bc02sc80i*, pci:v000014E4d0000432bsv*sd*bc02sc80i*, pci:v000014E4d0000432csv*sd*bc02sc80i*, pci:v000014E4d0000432dsv*sd*bc02sc80i*, pci:v000014E4d00004365sv*sd*bc02sc80i*, pci:v000014E4d00004353sv*sd*bc02sc80i*, pci:v000014E4d00004357sv*sd*bc02sc80i*, pci:v000014E4d00004358sv*sd*bc02sc80i*, pci:v000014E4d00004359sv*sd*bc02sc80i*, pci:v000014E4d00004331sv*sd*bc02sc80i*, pci:v000014E4d000043a0sv*sd*bc02sc80i*, pci:v000014E4d000043B1sv*sd*bc02sc80i*)
Original-Maintainer: Alberto Milone <alberto.milone@canonical.com>
```

"sudo updatedb && locate wl.ko" gives no output.

Second edit:

```
sebastien:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
[sudo] password for sebastien: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,545 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  bcmwl-kernel-source
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed/restricted bcmwl-kernel-source amd64 6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~0.1 [1,545 kB]
Fetched 1,545 kB in 1s (1,010 kB/s)              
(Reading database ... 297568 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~0.1_amd64.deb ...
Removing all DKMS Modules
Done.
Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~0.1) over (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~0.1) ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~0.1) ...
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom DKMS files...
Building only for 3.13.0-164-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Module build for the currently running kernel was skipped since the
kernel source for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for shim-signed (1.33.1~14.04.3+13-0ubuntu2) ...
Secure Boot not enabled on this system.
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4.11) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-164-generic
```

Comment: "modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found." Is this *after* you installed bcmwl-kernel-source? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes. I typed sudo apt-get install —reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source. The reinstallation went normally without errors, but I kept getting this output from modprobe afterwards.

Comment: Please edit your question to show: `sudo dpkg -s bcmwl-kernel-source` and also: `sudo updatedb && locate wl.ko` *updatedb* takes a few moments; please be patient.

Comment: Done. `sudo updatedb && locate wl.ko` gives no output

Comment: You are typing w-lower-case-L and not W-one, correct? It is wl as in WireLess. Very strange.

Comment: Yes. I am typing a lower case L.

Comment: Is there a make.log, perhaps at /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/4.18.0-12-generic/x86_64/log/make.log or some such? May we see it pasted here? http://paste.ubuntu.com Give us the link in your reply.

Comment: The directory /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/ only contains an empty directory named build and a source directory containing various items. Until recently, my laptop was taking too much time to boot and I found out I could correct that by deleting all the kernel images I had accumulated over the years except the current one. I followed the instructions found on that page https://gist.github.com/ipbastola/2760cfc28be62a5ee10036851c654600 Maybe I accidentally broke something along the way.

Comment: Yes, indeed! Please try: `sudo apt-get install —reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source` again and show us the results. Also, check for a new log that might have been created as a result. If so, paste it as above.

Comment: I added the output of the command as a second edit. As for log files, I found that an entry was added to /var/log/apt/term.log after executing the command. Here's the entry: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/VPZ83R9CFD/

Comment: As we see, the install did not go well: "Module build for the currently running kernel was skipped since the kernel source for this kernel does not seem to be installed." Please do: `sudo apt-get update` followed by: `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic` Then, if there are no errors, try again: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source`

Comment: May I write an answer that you may accept? Glad it’s working.

Comment: Yes of course. I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon investigation, we learned that the driver wouldn't properly compile because the required kernel headers were not installed:

> Module build for the currently running kernel was skipped since the
>   kernel source for this kernel does not seem to be installed. modprobe:
>   FATAL: Module wl not found.

I suggested that you do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

And, if there were no errors, then:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

I'm glad it is now working.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading a ubuntu 14.04 machine the wlan was not working anymore. What worked was a solution I found on Launchpad (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1818134). First, the package shim-signed is removed:

```
sudo apt remove shim-signed
```

and then the package bcmwl-kernel-source ist installed again (--reinstall should also work):

```
sudo apt remove bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source
```